# Can"t export test results (Resharper 2017.2)

Tags: resharper, resharper-2017

I want to export my test results but it doesn't show any results in the preview. Even after saving the file, it is empty.

[Empty Preview (Resharper)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGlsw.png)

Kind regards B0r1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problems anymore (made an update to 2017.3.3)